# How to read a single parquet file in S3 into pandas dataframe using boto3?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to read a single parquet file stored in S3 bucket and convert it into pandas dataframe using boto3.

Answer (score 7):

For python 3.6+ AWS has a library called [aws-data-wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) that helps with the integration between Pandas/S3/Parquet

to install do;

```
pip install awswrangler
```

to read a single parquet file from s3 using awswrangler 1.x.x and above, do;

```
import awswrangler as wr
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path="s3://my_bucket/path/to/data_folder/my-file.parquet")
```

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to simple read parquet file into dataframe with the utilization of boto3 package.

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd

# Read the parquet file
buffer = io.BytesIO()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('my-bucket-name','path/to/parquet/file')
object.download_fileobj(buffer)
df = pd.read_parquet(buffer)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Maybe simpler:
```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
df = pq.read_table('s3://blah/blah.parquet', filesystem=s3).to_pandas()
```

Answer (score 4):

There is info on using PyArrow to read a Parquet file from an S3 bucket into a Pandas dataframe here: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs

dataset = pq.ParquetDataset('s3://<s3_path_to_folder_or_file>', 
filesystem=s3fs.S3FileSystem(), filters=[('colA', '=', 'some_value'), ('colB', '>=', some_number)])
table = dataset.read()
df = table.to_pandas()
```

I prefer this way of reading Parquet from S3 because it encourages the use of Parquet partitions through the **filter** parameter, but there is a bug affecting this approach https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-2038.

Comment: That's a parquet dataset which I believe is a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simpler:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
df = pq.read_table('s3://blah/blah.parquet', filesystem=s3).to_pandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_parquet(
    full_s3_path,
    storage_options=dict(profile="<your_profile_name>")
)
```